C++ Windows Compatibility Mode full complete List?
I have received help here with setting the compatibility mode for my program via C++. I was looking for a full list of options for this and I have guessed at a lot. Please tell me what the following is missing and what is wrong if any. Thank you.
I was wanting a full list of compatibility data values to place into the registry. I did not find these sufficient to satisfy me, so I am asking here.
/// This is for UNICODE .  C++ CodeBlocks Registry editing.

    MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"Compatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\n", L"UNICODE version ? ? ?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);

    HKEY hKey = NULL;
    LPCWSTR subKey = L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\AppCompatFlags\\Layers";

    // RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY,LPCWSTR,DWORD,LPWSTR,DWORD,REGSAM,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,PHKEY,PDWORD);
    if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subKey, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
        {
            LPCWSTR valueName = L"C:\\ABCこんにちはDEFG A B C こ ん に ち は D E F G\\AこんにちはG A こ ん に ち は G.exe";
            LPCWSTR valueData = L"WIN98";


                //    Compatibility mode                Data value
                //    Windows 95                        WIN95
                //    Windows 98 / Windows ME           WIN98
                //    Windows NT 4                      NT4
                //    Windows NT 4 (Service Pack 1)     NT4SP1
                //    Windows NT 4 (Service Pack 2)     NT4SP2
                //    Windows NT 4 (Service Pack 3)     NT4SP3
                //    Windows NT 4 (Service Pack 4)     NT4SP4
                //    Windows NT 4 (Service Pack 5)     NT4SP5
                //    Windows 2000                      WIN2000 
                //    Windows 2000 (Service Pack 1)     WIN2000SP1 
                //    Windows 2000 (Service Pack 2)     WIN2000SP2 
                //    Windows 2000 (Service Pack 3)     WIN2000SP3
                //    Windows XP                        WINXP
                //    Windows XP (Service Pack 1)       WINXPSP1
                //    Windows XP (Service Pack 2)       WINXPSP2
                //    Windows XP (Service Pack 3)       WINXPSP3
                //    Windows Vista                     VISTARTM
                //    Windows Vista (Service Pack 1)    VISTASP1
                //    Windows Vista (Service Pack 2)    VISTASP2
                //    Windows 7                         WIN7RTM
                //    Windows 7 (Service Pack 1)        WIN7RTMSP1
                //    Windows 7 (Service Pack 2)        WIN7RTMSP2
                //    Windows 7 (Service Pack 3)        WIN7RTMSP3
                //    Windows 8                         WIN8RTM
                //    Windows 8.1                       ???
                //    Windows 10                        ???


            if (RegSetValueExW(hKey, valueName, 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)valueData, (lstrlen(valueData) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR)) == ERROR_SUCCESS) 
                {
                    MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"Compatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\n\nSTRING VALUE added successfully.", L"UNICODE version ? ? ?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                } 
            else 
                {
                    MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"Compatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\n\nFailed to set the STRING VALUE.", L"UNICODE version ? ? ?", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
                }

            RegCloseKey(hKey);

        } 
    else        // if (RegCreateKeyEx(   ) == ERROR_SUCCESS
        {
            MessageBoxExW(nullptr, L"Compatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\nCompatibility Mode\n\nFailed to create the REGISTRY KEY.\n\nRegCreateKeyExW(   ) != ERROR_SUCCESS", L"UNICODE version", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK, 0);
        }
    


Manually set those options in properties then open regedit.exe and inspect the value in there.

@AhmedAEK, Keeping it simple. I accept your comment as the answer.
